# Google Maps: Create marker from different class

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my android studio project, I have two activites: one MapsActivity and the other just basic.

When I click on the map, the other activity launches which consists of a set of EditTexts (textfields) allowing user to define custom properties for the marker. However, when I try to create the marker from that class, Android Studio gives me an error.

Here is the code, MapsActivity.java:

```
package com.geekybrackets.virtualtourguide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mMap;
    double lat = 0;
    double lon = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                lat = latLng.latitude;
                lon = latLng.longitude;
                startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, newMarker.class));



            }
        });


    }



}
```

NewMarker.java (activity where user enters properties of marker)

```
package com.geekybrackets.virtualtourguide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class newMarker extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_marker);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        Button save_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
                String marker_title = editName.getText().toString();
                MapsActivity i = new MapsActivity();
                i.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(i.lat, i.lon))
                        .title(marker_title));
                i.mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(i.lat, i.lon)));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the error i get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at com.geekybrackets.virtualtourguide.newMarker$2.onClick(newMarker.java:42)
```

How could i solve this issue? Any input wil be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh boy, you've got a couple of things to learn.

First, you should never invoke an `Activity`'s constructor - the idea is that the framework creates an instance of your `Activity` and you handle initialization logic on `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. If you just call the constructor, you create a random object which is not even going to be part of your UI, let alone the instance if `MapsActivity` with which you want to work.

Second, `newMarker` is a horrible class name, you should keep with the Java convention and start class names with an upper case letter, something like `NewMarkerActivity`,

Third, if you want to update `MapsActivity` from another `Activity`, you need to start the second activity *for a result* from the first activity. Basically, you should call `startActivityForResult(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, NewMarkerActivity.class))` instead of your current call, and override `onActivityResult` in `MapsActivity`. 
Pass the title as an extra in the result `Bundle` and retrieve it in `onActivityResult`.

[Consult the documentation for getting results](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Edit:
To pass the title, you need to create an `Intent` and pass in the title with a call to [`Intent.putExtra("someKey", theTitle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Afterwards,
 call [`Activity.setResult(int, Intent)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) with that `Intent`. In `onActivityResult`, you can get the title by calling [`getStringExtra("someKey")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String))

It's a good idea to make that key a `public static final` field of your `NewMarkerActivity` class, so that you don't make a typo.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. When receiving the result I get an intent, however I'm unsure of how to pass the 'title' as an extra. Documentation doesn't seem to help as well.

Comment: No problem. Check out the edit to see how you can pass your title around.

Comment: Ah, yep that sounds right, great! Thanks for the help again sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get instance of map this way. You are creating new instance of `MapsActivity` object that has mMap field set to null. You have to return value from `EditText` in `newMarker` via [setResult(int, Intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)). See more here: [Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: @npace was faster and he was not afraid to criticize, so I should reference to his reply.